# How to keep values of variable?

Tags: javascript, json, http

I don't know I can't access to values of the variable in Javascript.

`urli` have values like: `https://cors.io/?https://tb.rg-adguard.net/php/get_edition.php?version_id=11&lang=name_en`

But I tried to print values of `name_lang` with `console.log(this.namelang)` but it shows `undefine`

Here my code:

```
var urli = 'https://cors.io/?https://tb.rg-adguard.net/php/get_edition.php?version_id=' + version_id + "&lang=" + namelang;

$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: urli,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(response){
    var options = '';
    console.log(this.namelang);
    $.each(response.editions, function() {
        options += '<option value="' + this.edition_id + '" style="color: ' + this.color + '">' + this.namelang + '</option>';
    });

    $('#edition_id').html('<option value="0">- ' + seledition + ' -</option>'+options);
    $('#edition_id').attr('disabled', false);
    $('#language_id').html('<option>- ' + sellanguage + ' -</option>');
    $('#language_id').attr('disabled', true);
    $('#arch_id').html('<option>- ' + selachitecture + ' -</option>');
    $('#arch_id').attr('disabled', true);   
  }
});
```

Comment: the value of `urli` is wrong there are two`https` in the same url

Comment: @brk `urli` is correct. Did you try to load it? It is working fine

Comment: console.log(this.namelang);
shouldn't be console.log(response.namelang) ?

Comment: `namelang` only a parameter in URL

Comment: If it has to be the same variable as in the url then it is just `console.log(namelang)` without `this.` in front of it.

Comment: `namelang` is `name_en` in the case the language is English. `namelang` will change to `name_fr` in the case the language is France. Have javascript existed the method look like getting first columns in this array?

Comment: but namelang is inside an object (same object where the ajax call is made)? then you would need to make that = this before entering the ajax call, and then do that.namelang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you have `namelang` in your response???

I can not see `namelang` when I checked the URL. 
Below is response from the `urli`

```
{
  "editions": [
    {
      "name_en": "Windows 8.1 Pro + Core",
      "color": "green",
      "edition_id": "960032"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Windows 8.1 Pro N + Core N",
      "color": "green",
      "edition_id": "960033"
    }
  ]
}
```

After I understanding your requirements properly here I came up with the solution. You don't know what will be the language name, it can be `name_en` or `name_fr` but `name_` will be common. Right? If YES then below is the solution:

Working code snippet here:

```js
let response = {"editions":[{"name_en":"Windows 8.1 Pro + Core","color":"green","edition_id":"960032"},{"name_en":"Windows 8.1 Pro N + Core N","color":"green","edition_id":"960033"}]};


$.each(response.editions, function() {

  console.log(this.edition_id);
  console.log(this.color)

  let keysArr = Object.keys(this);
  let langname = "name_";

  for (var key in this) {
    if (key.substring(0, langname.length) === langname) {
      console.log(this[key]); // your desired value
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, it has the same result. `this.namelang = undefine`.

Comment: `namelang` only a parameter in url

Comment: yes. this should is `console.log(this.name_en)`. But when another language.This columns look like: `name_the_country_code`.

Comment: `namelang` is `name_en` in the case the language is English. `namelang` will change to `name_fr` in the case the language is France. Have javascript existed the method look like getting first columns in this array?

Comment: Thank you very much. You're awesome!

Answer (score 1):

That's because `this`, inside that callback, is just the JQuery xhr object, as seen here:

[image]

The `response` object contains what you want. But `namelang` is not inside that. The sample URL you gave has an array of two JSON objects.

[image]

To access, say, the first object's `color`, you'd take `response[0].color`.